# Why does grandchild of flex container overflow?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I have a flex container with a fixed width. It contains an intermediate container which contains a child that overflows.

Why does `overflow` on the child not work? If I delete the intermediate container it works as expected.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  max-width: 300px;
/*   WORKS */
/*   overflow-x: hidden; */
}

.container2 {
    border: 1px solid green;
/*   WORKS */
/*   overflow-x: hidden; */
}

.child {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: lightgrey;
/*   DOESN'T WORK! */
/*   overflow-x: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
      <div class="child">Superlongsuperlongsuperlongsuperlong</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try deleting `.container2` from the markup. Suddenly, `overflow-x` within `.child` works again. Why?

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `.container2`. https://jsfiddle.net/5upv9frL/